# Security issues in Electron using http:// protocol instead of file://?

Tags: node.js, security, electron

We've been developing an Electron app using Angular in the renderer and we have some background task services in main. We recently changed from loading `index.html` using the `file://` protocol. We just decided to implement Google Tag Manager into the solution, and using `http://` makes the implementation much easier as our Analyics experts easier can track the events they are interested in instead of contacting the developers to to some Analytics Universal stuff, we don't have to redeploy the app either each time we want to track something new.

However, when we load http://localhost:8888 using: (we have an express server listening and delivering the files)

```
win.loadURL(url.format({
  pathname: 'localhost:9696',
  protocol: 'http:',
  slashes: true
}));
```

We get warnings in dev-console:

```
Electron Security Warning (Node.js Integration with Remote Content) This renderer process has Node.js integration enabled and attempted to load remote content. This exposes users of this app to severe security risks.

For more information and help, consult https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security.
This warning will not show up once the app is packaged.
warnAboutNodeWithRemoteContent @node_modules/electron/dist/resources/electron.asar/renderer/security-warnings.js:145
loadHandler @node_modules/electron/dist/resources/electron.asar/renderer/init.js:173
12:59:08.193
```

My question is basically: Are these Warnings severe? Or can we ignore them? I'm trying to figure out what the risk could be for a user to access the localhost without SSL. Having a self signed certificate seams like overkill. Especially since electron apps can be unpacked and the certificates are accessible for everyone. How does this improve the security? All external content (only images), are accessed through `https://`.

Comment: This isn't about `http`/`https`, it's about the Node.js Integration. Electron warns you that every JavaScript loaded by that page may contain Node.js code which has access to your computers's file system. Theoretically, it could do something harmful; since its opening `localhost`, its not really something to worry about, but Electron does not make a difference over "normal" traffic. You might want to turn Node integration off, if you load foreign code via your `localhost` page, though.

Comment: Very good analysis from @AlexanderLeithner, but `localhost` HTTP isn't without risks. While it is less dangerous than remote URLs, it does allow privilege escalation. A malicious, but sandboxed, process could bind to :8888 before the express server does, and use that to gain access to the user's data. Given that :8888 is an incredibly popular port number and may be in use on many systems, you really want to use a random port anyway (but securing it is still challenging).

Comment: You also need to be careful with how the express server binds to :8888, or other systems on the network may be able to connect to express. This may open security problems of its own, or it may just expose the user to remote exploits against express itself. In any case, securing this system is much harder than what it's replacing.

Comment: I've been thinking about doing the same thing with my Electron apps. I thought it might be better to load from http://localhost instead of file://. As long as Electron starts its web server and ensures it's working before creating the BrowserWindow, I think it would be ok. I like the idea of using a random port, too.